# c++ makefile with multiple program, autodetection of source files

Tags: c++, makefile, detect

I recently lost 5 hours to figure out how I could write the makefile I need. I'm not an informaticien or programmer so I'd like some comments on what I managed to do. I already looked a lot on different sites but still...

I need a makefile that creates different executables: `prog1`, `prog2`...

To create the `.o` files, as I have many files with many dependencies, I don't want to specify them all. So I want/need to use automatic variables with a pattern rule. To speed up the compilation I also take care to only recompile the modified files. I achieved this by using the `-MD` flag that creates a `.d` file saved in the `$(BUILD)` directory.

What I still can't do is to detect automatically which `.o` files `prog1` needs. So for now I have to specify them automatically... If you know how to do that automatically...

I also would like to save the `.o` files in the `$(BUILD)` directory, but I can't make it work.

Any advice are welcome !
Thx

```
CXX = g++

ERRORS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
LAPACK = -llapack -lblas
OPTION = -O3 -fopenmp

CXXFLAGS = $(LAPACK) $(ERRORS) $(OPTION)
LDFLAGS  = $(LAPACK) $(ERRORS) $(OPTION)

BUILD=build
SRCS=(wildcard *.cpp)

all:prog1 prog2 ...

prog1:prog1.o dep_only_for_prog_1.o dep_for_all_progs.o dep_for_some_progs.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(NOASSERT)

prog2:prog2.o dep_only_for_prog_2.o dep_for_all_progs.o dep_for_some_progs.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(NOASSERT)

...

%.o:%.cpp
    $(CXX) -MD -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(NOASSERT)  $< -o $@
    mv $(<:.cpp=.d) $(BUILD)

-include $(addprefix $(BUILD)/$(SRCS:.cpp=.d))

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(BUILD)/*
```

Comment: And how should the Makefile be able to know which files are for prog1, and which are for prog2? If you were to give this task to a human, what rules would you tell him/her so he/she would know which files belong to which program?

Comment: @Cornstalks: Let the linker sort it out. It understands the contents; make doesn't. (Which is why you need hacks like `.d` files in the first place)

Comment: @Cornstalks: I would say to a human, look at the inclusions in the main file, if there is 'dep1.hpp', look if there is a 'dep1.o', if yes include 'dep1.o'. Repeat this until all recursively included files have been checked... but maybe I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: @MSalters: How can I the linker sort it out?

Comment: There's no rule that says that for every `dep1.hpp` there must be a source file.  Some headers (especially in C++) don't have any source files.  Sometimes source files have no header file.  Sometimes source files do not have the same prefix as the header.  These are all perfectly legal.  MSalters: the linker _cannot_ sort it out.  Say you link two different object files and they both contain symbol `main`.  How would the linker choose the right one?  In short, sorry PinkFloyd but you're out of luck.  You have to explicitly write which sources belong to which programs in your makefile.

Comment: The other option you have is to split your programs up into different directories.  Then you can say _compile all the source files in this directory into `prog1`_; THAT is a heuristic that make could implement.

Comment: @MadScientist okay, so I can't do shorter/easier than what I did... sad. But I know that I could put the `.o` files in an other directory... I tried many solutions given on this website and others but I didn't manage to make it work. I have not found a case where the dependencies are automatically generated with `-MD` and where the `.o` files are saved somewhere else...

Comment: That's a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't get make to infer somehow which files belong to which programs, but you CAN make your makefile simpler to read and update.  Also you have a few bad things here, such as adding `$(LAPACK)` (which contains linker flags) to `$(CXXFLAGS)` (which are passed to the compiler).

Try:

```
PROGRAMS = prog1 prog2

prog1_SOURCES = prog1.cpp dep_only_for_prog_1.cpp \
                dep_for_all_progs.cpp dep_for_some_progs.cpp

prog2_SOURCES = prog2.cpp dep_only_for_prog_2.cpp \
                dep_for_all_progs.cpp dep_for_some_progs.cpp

#----- Don't need to change below here

CXX = g++

ERRORS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
LAPACK = -llapack -lblas
OPTION = -O3 -fopenmp

CXXFLAGS = $(ERRORS) $(OPTION)
LDFLAGS  = $(LAPACK) $(ERRORS) $(OPTION)

BUILD=build
SRCS := $(wildcard *.cpp)

all: $(PROGRAMS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(PROGRAMS): $$($$@_SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)
        $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(NOASSERT)

%.o : %.cpp
        $(CXX) -MD -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(NOASSERT)  $< -o $@
        mv $(<:.cpp=.d) $(BUILD)

-include $(addprefix $(BUILD)/$(SRCS:.cpp=.d))

clean:
        rm -f *.o $(BUILD)/*
```

Or you can use eval if you want.

Comment: I will certainly use your advice to simplify my code, but I wonder why to you use the `.cpp` extension for the `prog_SOURCES` ? I will look for eval, because I have no idea what you mean...

Comment: I simply prefer to list the source files.  It's more specific.  If you list an object file you have no idea what the original source file was (it could have been a `.c`, `.cpp`, or even `.f90` or whatever).  So if your makefile lists the source files you can easily convert those to object files.  But if you list the object files there's no way to get back the source files if you need them.  Here, you don't so it doesn't matter so much.  `eval` is an advanced topic for make.  I recommend you avoid it unless you absolutely have to have it as it can be hard to wrap your head around.

Comment: I tried your solution but for some reason the line : `$(PROGRAMS): $$($$@_SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)` was problematic, I had to replace it by `$(PROGRAMS): $$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $$($$@_SOURCES))`. But it works, thanks